# Inserting a New Column from Three Joined Tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I have four columns joined from three different tables

Column 1 contains their ID numbers

Column 2 and 3 their last name and first name respectively

Column 4 their addresses

```
SELECT 
    idno, lastname, firstname, address
FROM
    table1
        JOIN
    table2 ON table2.table2_pk = table1.table1_fk
        JOIN
    table3 ON table3.table3_pk = table2.table2_fk
ORDER BY acctnum ASC;
```

I want to add an extra column that will determine if the members are old and new to the group, such that those with id numbers from 1 to 50 are old, and 51 to 100 new.

What is the syntax of creating a new column from three joined tables?

Comment: Are you using sql-server or MySQL?

Comment: CASE statement is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    idno, lastname, firstname, address,
    case when idno <= 50 then 'OLD' else 'NEW' end status
FROM
    table1
        JOIN
    table2 ON table2.table2_pk = table1.table1_fk
        JOIN
    table3 ON table3.table3_pk = table2.table2_fk
ORDER BY acctnum ASC;
```

New column `status` returns flag bases on `idno` value as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Having joined tables doesn't have anything to do with adding an additional columns.  Just add it to the end:

```
SELECT idno, lastname, firstname, address, CASE table1.idno WHEN <= 50 THEN 'New' ELSE 'Old' END AS MemberStatus
```

You should also append the table name to each column.